# Average filter without built-in function

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am having a problem with the output. I am using 5*5 filter for making image smooth. As average filter smooth our image but this one is making the image more dull. Can anyone help me with this problem?

Input Image is:

[image]

```
img_2 = imread('White-Bars.png');
filter = ones(5 , 5)/25;
working_img = img_2(:,:,1);
img_4 = img_2(:,:,1);
[rows,cols] = size(working_img); sum=0;
for row=4:(rows-3) 
  for col=4:(cols-3)
    for rowindex=(-2): (3) 
      for colindex=(-2): (3)
        img_4(row,col) = mean2(double(working_img(row+rowindex,col+colindex)) * filter(1:5,1:5));
      end
    end
  end
end
subplot(1,2,1);
imshow(working_img);
subplot(1,2,2);
imshow(img_4);
```

So, this is the output:

[image]

Comment: what is the size of your filter? also try gaussian filter instead of simple averaging as simple averaging filter put box like artifacts in your image. Also show here your code also, so that we can see what's wrong with your code

Comment: Hey @AnderBiguri now can you help me with it?

Comment: when you have divided the filter with 25 then you don't have to use `mean2` function, that's it. Instead of `mean2` you have to sum the pixels

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You dont understand what you are doing!

This is clearly homework, so I am not providing full code. You are doing image convolution, which you can do with way better code, (`fft`, `conv2`, `imfilter`, etc) but I assume you are doing this for learning.

First, sit down with your lecture notes and learn what filtering is. When you apply a filter over a pixel (the first 2 loops are to choose each pixel in the image) what you want to do is multiply your chosen filter over that pixel, and all the surrounding pixels, and accumulate the result of that in the output image.

Once you are in a specific pixel (`row`,`col`), then you iterate around all the neighboring pixels, (offset by `rowindex`,`colindex`). For each of these, you want to multiply the current pixel to the filter **on that specific location**, i.e. 1 value, and add it to the result. Depends on what the filter is, it will do something different. In your case, a filter with all the same value will do an average. **You do not need to use the `mean2` function, the mathematics you are applying do the filtering**.

In short, this line is wrong:

```
img_4(row,col) = mean2(double(working_img(row+rowindex,col+colindex)) * filter(1:5,1:5));
```

Both the use of `mean2` and the index on the variable `filter`.

Video explaining convolution: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C_zFhWdM4ic

Comment: I wanted to ask you one thing more and i have added that as well in the answer so can you check that as well for me.

Comment: I am getting problem that how we can access neighbour pixels and then to multiply them with the filter. And i am also getting problem that without padding from which row and col we can start our input image array.

Comment: @blu. I am not going to make your homework. Its a waste of **your** time and money. I have already given you everything you need, please take 2 hours to study it *at least*